# QT example executables won't run, missing QT5Cored.dll

Tags: c++, qt

QT5Cored.dll is on my system @: C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin folder

The Analogclock example and other projects will run in the IDE, but can Not be run from the created .exe files. When the EXE is launched the QT5Cored.dll missing error occurs.
QT installed it & doesn’t know where it is?
Removed & reinstalled QT with same results.
[image]

Downloaded earler today.
Version: 3.3.1, QT 5.4.1(MSCV 2010, 32 Bit), Built on Feb 20, 2015.

Any suggestions appreciated.

New error after DLL filles added to exe directory.
[image]

Comment: What compiler do you use? By the way, Qt separates debug build and release build, and has different set of .dll for them. In your case, QT5Core**d**.dll is for debug build and QT5Core.dll is for release build. If you want an executable .exe in the future, make sure you choose the release build and the right .dll. Running debug build outside the Qt Creator makes no sense.

Comment: You're using a Qt compiled with MSVC, but somehow you refer to a Qt dll compiled using gcc? This is *never* going to work. Your application and Qt must be compiled using the same compiler.

Answer (score 39):

To run it outside of Qt Creator, you have two choices:

1. Copy the missing DLLs to the directory where the executable resides. For example if `analogclock.exe` is in `c:\examples`, then copy `C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin\Qt5Cored.dll` and other required DLLs to `c:\examples`. You may need to copy plugins files too.
2. Add `C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin` to the `PATH` environment variable.

There are some ways to copy the missing DLLs:

**1. Use Windows Deployment Tool (windeployqt.exe) to copy required files**

1. Open Command Prompt in one of the following way:

   1. If you use MSVC as compiler, open the correct Visual Studio Command Prompt. For example for VS2013 32-bit, click `Start -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 -> Visual Studio Tools -> VS2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt`. This will open a Command Prompt with the `VCINSTALLDIR` environment variable correctly set. `windeployqt.exe` requires this environment variable to copy the correct Visual C++ redistributable executable.
   2. If you use MinGW, just open a Command Prompt.
2. Add Qt binary path and optionally `g++.exe` path to PATH environment variable. If your executable is 32-bit, add the 32-bit Qt binary path, eg: `c:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013\bin`. If your executable is 64-bit, add the 64-bit Qt binary path, eg: `c:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64\bin`. `windeployqt.exe` will copy DLLs from this directory, so it is important that you don't set 32-bit Qt binary path for a 64-bit executable, vice versa. You need to add `g++.exe` path too if you use MinGW, windeployqt will copy lib*.dll from there.

   ```
   ; Example path for MSVC 32-bit
   PATH=c:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013\bin;%PATH%

   ; Example path for MinGW 32-bit, g++.exe is in C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin
   PATH=C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin;C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin;%PATH%
   ```
3. Run `windeployqt.exe` with your executable file as argument. Eg:

   ```
   windeployqt.exe C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.4\widgets\richtext\build-calendar-Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MSVC2013_32bit-Debug\debug\calendar.exe
   ```
4. Check the output for error or warning. The following is an output without error and warning:

[image]

**2. Manually copy the DLLs**

You must copy the correct DLLs (32-bit or 64-bit). Use a tool like [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find the correct DLL paths:

1. Run the application from Qt Creator / Visual Studio.
2. Open Process Explorer.
3. In Process Explorer

   1. Click the executable, for example `calendar.exe`
   2. Press `Ctrl+D` to show loaded DLLs in the lower panel. The equivalent menu is `View -> Lower Panel View -> DLLs`
   3. In the lower panel, click the `Path` column to sort by path.
4. Copy the DLLs to the directory where the executable resides. For example in the following picture. The DLLs are from C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013\bin.

[image: Process Explorer]

5. If your executable uses something like `c:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.dll`. It should be copied too. But copy from the `platforms` directory, not `plugins`. Let's say `calendar.exe`'s full path is `c:\examples\calendar.exe`, then `qwindowsd.dll` should be copied to `c:\examples\platforms\qwindows.dll`, not `c:\examples\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll`.
6. You need to copy C++ runtime library too. If you are using mingw, you may need to copy `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll`. `libwinpthread-1.dll` etc too. Check in Process Explorer to be sure. If you are using MSVC, you need to deploy the runtime (Eg: `msvcp120.dll`, `msvcr120.dll`). At the end, your directory structure is something like this:

   ```
   c:\examples\calendar.exe
   c:\examples\Qt5Cored.dll
   c:\examples\Qt5Widgetsd.dll
   c:\examples\Qt5Guid.dll
   c:\examples\icudt53.dll
   c:\examples\icuin53.dll
   c:\examples\icuuc53.dll
   c:\examples\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll   (if using mingw)
   c:\examples\libstdc++-6.dll      (if using mingw)
   c:\examples\libwinpthread-1.dll  (if using mingw)
   c:\examples\platforms\qwindowsd.dll
   ```

Comment: Thanks.  I should have remembered that I needed to add the dlls in old VB6 project installers, but haven't lately using U++.  I added three dll files to the dir containing the exe, now I'm getting an unidentified error.  See image in my original question. Looking for Env. path dir input loc.  I'm new to QT.

Comment: You might also try the deployment tool.  We use it and are happy with it.  It's described at the bottom of this page: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: @RetiredNinja, thanks for the tip! Added steps to use the tool.

Comment: My install created with`windeployqt` also doesn't run on non-qt machine. I realized it doesn't copy msvcp100.dll (a VV2010 dll that I am using) to the installation which I can see through ProcessExplorer (there are many other files too). I did start the command prompt through VC2010 IDE but it doesn't copy any additional files than if I do in a start menu > command prompt.

Comment: @zadane, `windeployqt` does not copy msvcp100.dll, but it should copy the VC++ redistributable installer (eg. `vcredist_x86.exe`) which the end users can install, provided that `VCINSTALLDIR` is set correctly before you run `windeployqt`. If it doesn't, you can always copy `vcredist_x86.exe` yourself :)

Comment: That is one hell of a good reply.  I cannot believe it's not marked as the answer

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution for me was just adding the QTDIR C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2017_64\ to your Windows system variables.

1. In Windows search, type 'env' and press "Edit the system environment variables"
2. Press "Environment Variables" below
3. In the System variables list, press "New..."
4. Add `QTDIR` as variable name, with value the directory name of the compiler under the Qt directory: `C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32` in your case

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by *fxam* is an in-depth, comprehensive one. I have tried the approaches provided and they work!

Just add a comment that in case of MinGW64, one should run windeplyqt.exe in the directory of "C:\Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_64\bin".

*DrumM*'s answer is the simplest solution. It has been mentioned as 1.2. in *fxam*'s answer though.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Retired Ninja in the comments, If you are on windows you can also use the [Windows Deployment Tool](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool).

As per the link:

> The tool can be found in QTDIR/bin/windeployqt. It needs to be run within the build environment in order to function correctly.

> windeployqt takes an .exe file or a directory that contains an .exe file as an argument, and scans the executable for dependencies.

You can add it to your **build steps** using the following:

1. Create a **Custom Process Step**:

[image]

2. You can fill out the form now:

   - **Commands**: Path of the windeployqt (can be found at QTDIR/bin/windeployqt)
   - **Arguments**: Type of binary to assume, Path to the app binary/Folder containing the app binary

[image]

You can see more details about the different arguments [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool).