# Cannot run application in release mode after Qt updated. Could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"

Tags: qt

I just updated Qt using Maintenance Tool. Now when I run application in release mode I get error.

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".
>
> Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, windows.
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

This solution did not help me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20496175/1034253

In debug mode the application works good.

Comment: Try using [Windows Deployment Tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732602/qt-example-executables-wont-run-missing-qt5cored-dll/28732893#28732893)

Comment: Are you trying to run it from the Qt creator? You might need to remove the build directory entirely because Qt 5.4.0 was not binary compatible on Windows.

Comment: @SimonWarta from Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1):

check the other Qt dlls in your executable directory. For release mode you must always use the release version of the dlls. For Example Qt5Core.dll instead of Qt5Cored.dll