# Release version of program built in VS2015 with Qt runs then closes without errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I'm trying to build a release version of my chess engine that was built in the Qt environment and recently ported over to the visual studio 2015 environment. Everything runs fine in debug, and using this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732602/qt-example-executables-wont-run-missing-qt5cored-dll) I was able to use windeployqt.exe to get dependencies that were giving error messages.

But now when I run it, it shows up in the process explorer for about 3-4 seconds then disappears. It's not throwing any errors so I'm not sure what's wrong. It could be it needs a dependency that I haven't copied yet? There's nothing that I know of that would cause it to run and quit, it never does that during debug.

Any tips or direction as to where to look for an answer would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Build the debug build and check the output when the program runs.

Comment: There's a fair number of warnings like 'y' : unrefrenced formal parameter, etc. At the end it says ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========. When the program runs there's quite a lot of output that looks like Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Comment: Does your program depend on any plugin? images, database etc?

Comment: It uses Qtcore, QtGui, and QtWidgets but I have those dll's in the folder. It also has images it needs, that might be it!

Comment: I put the images into the release folder in an identical file name but that didn't do the trick sadly :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As trivial as it may sound, welcome to C++! You're programming in a very low level language that errors may some times crash your program with no apparent erros. This is not Java or Python or some high-level language where everything is done for you. In other words, if you mess up, you probably could get weird crashes like you're having.

There are many things you can do:

1. Delete all your compiled files and rebuild them from scratch. Linking issues with legacy code often cause what you're describing
2. If you added a list of libraries to link to (other than Qt), make sure that you need every library of them. Create a new "Hello world" program and link to them, and see if you'll get the same crash.

If it's not a linking issues, you're most likely having an access violation (or segfault).

3. Run the program in debug mode, and see if you get any information about the error.
4. The last resort is the low-level, stupid, binary search `cout`ing method. Basically you print a message in various places in your program, and see at which message the propgram will stop. The reason I call it "[binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)", is because if have N places to test, with a binary testing approach you only need about log(N) compiles to find the problem, which is not a lot, but will cost you some time to recompile the program. In other words: Keep printing messages until you see where they stop appearing, and then blame that line.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely put a cout in the main to make sure it's even loading anything at all! My guess is it's something to do with the dll's for visual studio because I've been able to build and run it from the Qt side of things.

Comment: It never does anything with cout loop in the very first line of main, just runs for a second or 3 then closes. Is it possible I'm missing dll's for visual studio that I need? Or the compiler that visual studio uses?

Comment: You probably are linking with incompatible libraries. Keep in mind that in Windows, debug libraries are not the same as release libraries.

Comment: debug libraries normally end with d don't they? Also, If it's not throwing an error when starting that should mean that i might just have the wrong version of the library not missing any?

Comment: @MaxC Yes, usually they end with "d". It could mean many things. Linking is not a simple problem. Get ready to spend a day to fix this issue. Try to replace the libraries you're using, and check online for similar problems for every library you're using, also try to use the same libraries in other "Hello world" programs to see which one causes the crash.

Comment: Ugh, I was able to build the deployed debug version of the program just fine  just now, with the qt tool I mentioned above. I'll keep trying things. Thanks a bunch for the insight!

Comment: hi MaxC, you can use dependency walker to scan your project and see if it is a dll problem or not, it is available on this link : http://www.dependencywalker.com/